# Used to refer to what has been just mentioned

Tags: meaning

Recently I read a book where I found a word which meaning, after I checked, is something like this:

> Used to refer to what has been just mentioned/said previously.

Now I need that word because I am writing something. Do you know what is it?

Comment: So you have the meaning but not the word.  Maybe "quote"?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the word and because I gave back that book to the library after I finished it, I can not provide the quote either, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [aforementioned](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aforementioned) (adjective) -  Denoting a thing or person previously mentioned.